# Modern trends for web designing: help me choose a font-family

Tags: css

I want someone to recommend me fonts that are "in" now-a-days and should be available on most platforms. You see, I am a web-programmer and not much of a web designer. I am asked to use serif fonts.

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://doctype.com/

Comment: Avenir is a awsOme font. Just Use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found [8 Definitive Web Font Stacks](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/eight-definitive-font-stacks) by Michael Tuck a good read to start with.

Answer (score 6):

I'd second the recommendation for the [SitePoint font stacks article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/eight-definitive-font-stacks#) already mentioned, and also point out that typography is more than just picking the right fonts - there are a couple of excellent articles recently published that are well worth a read:

1. [Typography is the backbone of good web design](http://www.thedesigncubicle.com/2009/11/typography-is-the-backbone-of-good-web-design/)
2. [Jason Santa Maria's On Web Typography](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/on-web-typography/)

It's also worth mentioning that css3's @font-face is very usable these days with surprisingly good browser support (See [CSS At Ten](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten) and [Typekit](http://typekit.com/) for more info, and the *excellent* [modernizr javascript library](http://www.modernizr.com/) to help with cross browser (that is IE) support).

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally steer clear of serif fonts as I don't think they work too well for web content.  Having said that, Georgia isn't too bad as a choice if it's got to be serif.

Comment: The "modern Georgia-based serif stack" in Residuum's link would be a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

Try pairing serifs with sans-serifs. For a classic pairing consider georgia for headings and verdana for body text.

You might also want to check out [Type Kit](http://typekit.com) if you would like to use non-standard fonts without having to use Fahrner image replacement to display non-standard fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Futura is Great font to make your Design look's Great. You just have to know how to use it. it also depend on what kind of design you are working on. Futra and Circular are the fonts you need to use.

Comment: IMO he managed to found a font. It's been 6 years and a half now ..